# Understanding beavhiour change between: import modname -> and -> from modname import membername

Tags: python, python-import

I am posting a compact example of a program of 3 small files, and I want to understand why changing a couple lines makes this difference.

```
# main.py

from renderer import Renderer
import shared

class Application():
    def __init__(self):
        self.isRunning = True
        self.renderer = Renderer()
        self.globalize()
    def globalize(self):
        shared.app = self

def main():
    app = Application()
    while ( app.isRunning ):
        app.renderer.quit()
    print "program end"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

```
# shared.py
app = None
```

---

```
# renderer.py
import shared
class Renderer():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def quit(self):
        shared.app.isRunning = False
```

Now, this usage of the file `shared.py` gives the `Renderer` class access to the `Application` class, which has an instance of `Renderer` as a member, for whatever diabolical program design I had in mind. And my question is why this access is no longer guaranteed when `renderer.py` is changed as follows:

---

```
# renderer.py -- ( new )
from shared import app
class Renderer():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def quit(self):
        app.isRunning = False
```

---

The original `renderer.py` made the program end, and the later `renderer.py` raises an exception, why is this?

```
renderer.py", line 7, in quit
app.isRunning = False
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isRunning'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python modules are objects and names in the module are attributes of this module. When imported (from the same path) module instances are "stored" in `sys.modules`. In the first case, both `main` and `renderer` share a reference to the same module instance, so when `main` rebinds `shared.app` this is also visible in `renderer`. In the second case, you make `app` a local (module local that is) name, so rebinding `shared.app` doesn't impact what `renderer.app` is bound to. The important point here is that Python's "variables" have very few in common with C variables. The latter are symbolic names for memory addresses, while in Python they are just key->value pairs, the key (name) belonging to a namespace (module namespace, class namespace, function's local namespace). So the

```
from module import something
```

line is just shortcut for:

```
import module
# create a local name 'something' 
something = module.something 
del module

# at this point both module.something and something are bound to the 
# same object, but they are distinct names in distinct namespaces

# rebinds local name 'something'
# now `module.something` and `something` point to dffererent objects
something = object()
```

FWIW your design is not "diabolical", it's just EvilGlobals all the way. The simple and obvious way to give `Renderer` access to the current `app` instance is to pass `app` to renderer:

```
class Renderer(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

class Application(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.renderer = Renderer(self)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can think of your statement

```
from shared import app
```

as equivalent to

```
import shared
app = shared.app
```

Here, you have two distinct variables. Changing one does not change the other. When the import happens, `app` is set to `None`. Even if `shared.app` changes value, the `app` variable in this module will not change its value. When you call `app.isRunning`, app is still `None` and you get the error.

The first case works as you expect because you are always accessing `shared.app`.